# What technique for matching parameters of objects?

Tags: regression, matching

Assume I have a set of samples described by continuous parameters. Now, I want to match the samples maximizing some goodness of fit metric, two at a time. E.g., predict the reaction time of two molecules based on their parameters. The training set would be a set of molecules together with reaction time for each possible two pairs.

How would you model this?

Would you hand craft the feature combinations of the two samples and feed them to e.g. a regression model?